How to loop through a dataframe to create a table of contents in quarto
I have a data frame df_full that I want to loop through to create a table of contents in quarto. I want each heading to be unique(df_full$Topic), each subheading to be unique(df_full$question_id) within each topic, and the content displayed to be unique(df_full$response).
My attempt is this:
---
title: "PSP ESG and Impact Orientation QAQC"
format:
  html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 2
    number-sections: true
    toc-location: left
    css: corp-styles_2023-new-logo.css
    self-contained: true
editor: visual
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

# Loop through unique topics
for (topic in unique(df_full$Topic)) {
  cat("#", topic, "\n")  # Main section for each Topic

  # Filter to get questions and responses for the current topic
  topic_data <- df_full |>  
    filter(Topic == topic)

  for (i in 1:nrow(topic_data)) {
    # Use Question as a subsection
    cat("## Question:", topic_data$Question[i], "\n") 
    # Add the dummy response
    cat("### Response:", topic_data$dummy_response[i], "\n") 
  }
}

but the results just display as text like this:
# ESG Governance and Disclosure 
## Question: Formal ESG policy or policies on relevant environmental, social, governance topics? 
### Response: Yes, policy or strategy in place 
## Question: Formal ESG policy or policies on relevant environmental, social, governance topics? 
### Response: Yes, policy or strategy in place 
## Question: Formal ESG policy or policies on relevant environmental, social, governance topics? 
### Response: Yes, policy or strategy in place


Perhaps edit your question and try to describe your desired output / behaviour a bit. Currently you have enabled automatic toc generation in YAML block and then you  generate a set of headings, which in turn will be used by quarto to generate a toc.  Are those headings meant to replace quoarto-generated toc? Or is just a first step in the process of generating whole report programmatically?
And for raw markdown output you do need to set output: asis

This is the first step to programmatically building out the quarto doc. With my current code, the headings are being produced and no toc is being generated.

If your code generates raw Markdown and you want to keep it as-is, you should also set output (or results) option accordingly, e.g. :
```{r}
#| output: asis

cat("# Topic\n")
```


Complete qmd for reference:
---
format:
  html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 2
    number-sections: true
    toc-location: left
    self-contained: true
editor: visual
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```{r}
#| label: setup

library(dplyr)
df_full <- tribble(
  ~Topic, ~Question, ~dummy_response,
  "A", "B", "C"
)
```

Code-block with `output: asis`:
```{r}
#| label: with-output-asis
#| output: asis

# Loop through unique topics
for (topic in unique(df_full$Topic)) {
  cat("#", topic, "\n")  # Main section for each Topic

  # Filter to get questions and responses for the current topic
  topic_data <- df_full |>  
    filter(Topic == topic)

  for (i in 1:nrow(topic_data)) {
    # Use Question as a subsection
    cat("## Question:", topic_data$Question[i], "\n") 
    # Add the dummy response
    cat("### Response:", topic_data$dummy_response[i], "\n") 
  }
}
```
---
Code-block without `output: asis` :

```{r}
#| label: without-output-asis

cat("#", topic, "\n") 
cat("## Question:", topic_data$Question[i], "\n") 
cat("### Response:", topic_data$dummy_response[i], "\n") 
```

Renders as:


Oh, right - thank you!
